# What is Phone Window Decor View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-include

I tried getting the root view of a layout I'm including (include tag). Instead of the initial Relative Layout that I used, it returned Phone Window Decor View. What is it? How come it's not under the relative layout?

Structure below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:tag="rlMain"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/lightest_gray"> 

  <include layout="@layout/include_attachment_options" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: dump your view hierarchy by running `adb shell dumpsys activity top` and you will see the whole view tree

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to get the Root View? 
Phone Window Decor view is the top-level view, and everything else (your activity) is a child to that.

Refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html

> Abstract base class for a top-level window look and behavior policy. An instance of this class should be used as the top-level view added to the window manager. It provides standard UI policies such as a background, title area, default key processing, etc.
>
> The only existing implementation of this abstract class is android.view.PhoneWindow, which you should instantiate when needing a Window.

If you want to get the full view hierarchy, try the UI Automator Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Simply put, Decor-view is what you see a moment before the activity layout inflates. Usually, it's just a white screen.
2. In order to get hold of the root view of the included layout you should give it an ID in the layout file (include_attachment_options.xml) and then look it up like:

   RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);